# For a diagonalizable matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

'' For a diagonalizable matrix $A$ the matrices $P$ and $D$ such that $A = PDP^{-1}$

Comment: no........................

Comment: why, can you elaborate please?

Comment: let $A$ and $D$ be the identity and $P$ any orthogonal matrix

Comment: ahhh, i always  forget about identity, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some examples:

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\end{align*}

In general, the columns of the matrix $P$ can be chosen to be a basis of eigenvectors for the matrix $A$. There will always be infinitely many such bases, as you can always scale any basis vector by a constant. Moreover, you can swap the order of the basis vectors (i.e. swap the order of the columns), which will swap the order of the eigenvalues on the diagonal of $D$. So, $D$ is not unique either.